# Running Superset on Azure container Instance

Tags: azure, apache-superset, azure-container-instances, azure-storage-account, azure-storage-files

I am trying to run superset on Azure container Instance with volume mapping on Azure file Share storage. When I build the container with below command the container instance gets on the running state but I can't launch the superset url.

`az container create --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name superset01 --image superset-image:v1 --dns-name-label superset01 --ports 8088 --azure-file-volume-account-name $ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --azure-file-volume-account-key $STORAGE_KEY --azure-file-volume-share-name $ACI_PERS_SHARE_NAME --azure-file-volume-mount-path "/app/superset_home/"`

Also I can see the volume map files are created on the file share but it doesn't grow to the initial size of superset.db.

```
Name                 Content Length    Type    Last Modified
-------------------  ----------------  ------  ---------------
cache/                                 dir
superset.db          0                 file
superset.db-journal  0                 file
```

Any inputs on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested in my environment, and it is working fine for me. I am using ***[superset images](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset)*** from ***docker hub*** and pushed to container registry.

***Use below command to pull the superset images from dockerhub***

```
docker pull apache/superset
```

[image]

**Tag the Superset images to push in Container registry**

```
docker tag 15e66259003c testmyacr90.azurecr.io/superset
```

[image]

Now login in the conatiner registry

```
docker login testmyacr90.azurecr.io
```

**And then push the images to Container Repositoty**

[image]
[image]

***You can use the below cmdlet to create the `Container Instace` and mount to a `FileShare` as well***

```
az container create --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name mycontainerman --image $ACR_LOGIN_SERVER/superset:latest --registry-login-server $ACR_LOGIN_SERVER --registry-username $ACR_USERNAME --registry-password $ACR_PASSWORD --dns-name-label aci-demo-7oi --ports 80 --azure-file-volume-account-name $ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --azure-file-volume-account-key $STORAGE_KEY --azure-file-volume-share-name $ACI_PERS_SHARE_NAME --azure-file-volume-mount-path /aci/logs/
```

[image]
[image]

Would suggest you use **`FDQN`** or **`Public IPAddress`** of container instance to hit on browser and able to see response from container instance.

***Update-----***

**I have mounted the fileShare at `"/app/superset_home/` as you did and getting the same output like you.**

[image]

Based on above picture would suggest you to do not mount the ***fileshare*** at `/app/superset_home/` because here `superset.db` and `superset.db-journal` resides. if we are mounting to this location there is conflict happing. So better to suggest you mount at `/aci/logs/` or any location you want rather than `/app/superset_home/`

**Update 2-------**

As I am using the same storage account for mount the vloume at `/aci/logs/` as previously volume mounted to `/app/superset_home/`.

Getting the same error like you

[image]

***Soultion: To avoid thease kind of issue create a new storage accout and file share with in and mount the volume at `/aci/logs/`.***

Once i did like that i sorted my issue

[image]

Comment: I did mostly the same as you have suggested. You have used aci/logs for the volume mount path instead. I tried that as well and I can launch the superset url now. but still the volume mapping doesnt seems to be working as after restarting the ACI instance I am loosing my changes in report/dashboards.

Comment: Hello @Sunil, I have updated the answer. Please check

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Rahul, however I did used /aci/logs/ as the mount path and was able to launch superset url but it doesnt helped in container volume mapping. if I restart my container instance all changes are reset to initial state.

Comment: Hello @Sunil, Please check my update2.

Comment: Hi @RahulKumarShaw-MT, Truly appreciate your prompt response on this issue. I did create a new file share this time and mounted /aci/logs on that file share, but still not able to map volume for superset. I can’t see any files in the newly created file share after the instance initiated. Not sure what wrong am I doing. BTW I am using custom Superset registory to include few DB packages. Should there be any mapping information provided in the custom dockerfile as well?

Comment: Custome superset should not be problem. Create new storage account and new fileshare .Not only the new file share in existing storage account.and using new storage account and file share create new ACI using the script I have given earlier in answer itself ,that will work only.