# Why can't I use azure file share in my docker-compose to store mongodb data in Azure Container Instance?

Tags: mongodb, azure, docker-compose, azure-storage

When using a docker ACI context, the following docker-compose file fails.  The mongodb container continuously restarts.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:5.0.6
    env_file: mongo.env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeit
    ports:
      - 27017
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: mongodb-data
      storage_account_name: kpncoqyuxumoetuftz
```

If I don't use the azure_file storage it will run ok (But of course the data won't be persistent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why I can't mount to the default directory `/data/db` but to get this to work I had to mount to a different directory and then replace the default command with one that takes a parameter.

Working version is below:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:5.0.6
    command: ["mongod", "--dbpath=/dbdata"]
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeit
    ports:
      - 27017
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/dbdata

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: mongodb-data
      storage_account_name: kpncoqyuxumoetuftz
```

Comment: This is because this location get reserved for your mongodb images(ACI) so if you mount a volume as refernece of fileshare won't work . You have to choose a diffrent directory.

Comment: You can check this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71066153/running-superset-on-azure-container-instance/71111838?noredirect=1#comment125725032_71111838) which i answred yesterday related to same issue.

Comment: Any tips on doing file mounts with the azure_file driver? I need to load config files for the containers. Doing - dbdata/config.yml:/dbdata/config.yml ( as example ) does not seem to work